# Nvidia Drivers Removal + locating suitable drivers, how?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, uninstall

Would it work if I were to do the removal of the Nvidia drivers using Synaptic's Removal Complete, then, without rebooting (to avoid Ubuntu choosing drivers on its own during the booting process/loading) do the installation of the new drivers via the Terminal commands to install the latest as shown in [Softpedia](http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Install-the-Latest-NVIDIA-331-20-Drivers-in-Ubuntu-13-10-399182.shtml)?

Sorry I ask instead of trying myself. But I'm at work as I type this :( + being a family man my time is so precious if you know what I mean.

Thanks in advance guys/gals,

JDL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**to remove nvidia drivers **

Open a terminal. ctrl+alt+T
and type in:

> sudo apt-get --purge nvidia-current -y

you find the correct drivers for your nvidia card , well from nvidia.com
http://www.nvidia.co.uk/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-uk

download it, and

1. Open a terminal. ctrl+alt+T
2. Navigate to the directory of the .run file. For this example, I have mine on the desktop so I would type in "cd ~/Desktop" and press enter.
3. Type "chmod +x example.run" (press enter).
4. Now type "./example.run", press enter, and the installer will run.

Comment: BD Bear, thank you so much for such a clear and complete answer! :)
One last question on this before I follow your instructions, to be on the safe side: 
Should anything go wrong, by restoring from the backup I did today with Backup in Ubuntu would I be back to where I was before I installed this?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem

Comment: You can test div stuff, inside virtual environments like oracle Viritualbox (free) or vmware workstation (payed). Personally i prefer VMware workstation since you can visualize your physical machine, so its an cloned version on the computer your running. (program are free to test for 30 days.)

Comment: Thanks for replying BD Bear. 
I hope my restoring from the Backup will include my video card drivers settings too though. I ignore how many steps are necessary to setup a VM, but I know doing a restoration is pretty easy ;)